# unixODBC and iODBC installed at the same time?

Tags: libreoffice, mariadb, odbc

Is there any conflict with having unixODBC and iODBC installed at the same time?

(It seems that some programs might depend on one or the other, at least if I try to uninstall iODBC, it also wants to unistall a bunch of other things like calligra and kexi.)

I'm having trouble getting LibreOffice to connect using ODBC to either a MariaDB or MDBTools database, that is without crashing.

See full report and question [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/79135/how-do-i-set-up-a-odbc-connector-for-mariadb-or-mysql-in-base/).